# Unable to resolve AWS account to use when running CDK in a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk

I tried to run `cdk` inside a docker container. Everything works fine until I try to deploy using command:

`cdk deploy myStack --profile testing --require-approval never`

Error

```
 ❌  MyStack failed: Error: Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK or through the environment
```

I have created both `config` and `credentials` file under docker container's `/root/.aws/` folder, since it will match the `~/.aws`

I use this setting in my laptop and it works fine. In my laptop, those two files are under `/Users/<my user name>/.aws`.

My docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.3
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=c35a1803a6e70a126e80b2b3ae33eed961f83ed74d18fcd16909b2d44d7dada3203f1ffe726c17ef8dcca2dcaa9fca676987befeadc9b9f759967a8cb77181c0
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      curl procps \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install

RUN node -v
RUN npm -v

RUN npm install -g aws-cdk

RUN mkdir /usr/local/TestingCDK;
COPY ./src /usr/local/TestingCDK/src/
COPY pom.xml /usr/local/TestingCDK/
COPY cdk.json /usr/local/TestingCDK/
RUN cd /usr/local/TestingCDK/ && mvn compile
RUN mkdir ~/.aws
RUN cd ~ && pwd
COPY config /root/.aws/
COPY credentials /root/.aws/


CMD cdk doctor ; cat ~/.aws/config ; cd /usr/local/TestingCDK/ ; cdk deploy myStack --profile myProfile --require-approval never
```

Comment: Which image are you using?

Comment: @AmitBaranes I added the docker file I am using.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the keys and other variables into the container and set AWS_ environment variables instead, to name a few

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

see here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

saving and copying your access/secret keys into the container is a very bad practice.